# CWAC library video recording on portrait mode results in video rotated to bad landscape

Tags: android, video, android-orientation, commonsware-cwac

I am using the CWAC library and trying to record videos like Vine and Instagram, portrait mode. However, the videos recorded come up in bad landscape(they get rotated to landscape and somehow lose their proper ratios). any idea on why and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the Known Limitations section of the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#known-limitations):

> Taking videos in portrait mode is not supported

There is [an outstanding issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/133) to try to support it. Note that I suspect that the vast majority of devices will still give the same results that you are seeing, which is why I formally dropped support for it.

Note that Vine does not use `MediaRecorder` to take videos, as my library does. They build their own videos using camera preview frames, probably in conjunction with a port of `ffmpeg` or something like that to convert those frames into a video.